# How to Check if website is Up/Down using linux

Tags: bash, xmlhttprequest

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
MYHOST="https://www.testwebsite.com"
#Check if Website is up or down
if wget -S $MYHOST 2>&1 | grep -w "200\|301\" > /dev/null
then
echo "Website is up"
else
#Website is down"
Send mail / mailx to send email
```

Script can send an email alert if website is down but it sends repeated emails until it is up.

How to:

1. Send an email alert if website is down but alert should be sent only once.
2. If it is up, email should be sent as up.

One email for website down and up.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I would wrap the whole if statement in a while and create a variable to indicate if the mail is sent

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
MYHOST="https://www.testwebsite.com" # website
sent=false # sent?

while true
do
  get=$(wget -S $MYHOST 2>&1 | grep -w "200\|301")
  if [ "$get" != "" ] # wget to the website
  then
    # website is up
    echo "Do Something"
  else
    # website is down
    if ! $sent # if the email hasn't been sent yet
    then
      mailx ...
      sent=true
    fi
  fi
done
```